# undefined method `each' and cannot tell why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm receiving this error message and I'm not exactly sure why. My controller actions are:

```
def create
    @wad = Wad.new(wad_params)
    if @wad.save    
        redirect_to wad_path
    else
        render 'new'
        flash[:error] = "Failed to submit (missing paramters). Please try again!"
    end
end
def index
    @wads = Wad.all
end
```

My view is:

```
<h1>Page for wads</h1>
<% @wads.each do |wad|%>
<%= wad.problem_state %>
<%= wad.short_form %>
<%= wad.long_form %>
<% end %>
```

Any thoughts on why this wouldn't work?

Comment: On what line is this error occurring on?

Comment: What is the value in `@wads`, I think `@wads` will be nil ?

Comment: Check in console `Wad.all` , whether you have data in database or not.

Comment: `Wad.all` would return `[]`, so `each` would be defined.

Comment: Have you defined any method `all` which is overriding the default behaviour..?

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error message `undefined method`each' for `nil:NilClass`
Then, the problem is not about `each` but the `NilClass`.

You should check the object, `@wads` in your case.

From the `index` method, `@wads` is the result of calling `Wad.all`, so you should check this statement in your console.Make sure the result of `Wad.all` is not nil.

Comment: it's not I have two instances of wads